# Uniqueness of the modal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Suppose that matrix $A$ is diagonalizable, i.e. there exists an invertible matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ so that $P^{-1}AP=D$. We know that (i) we can form $P$ from eigenvectors of $A$ and (ii) $P$ and $D$ are not unique as we can change their column.

My questions are that:

1. Is it correct that the columns of $P$ must be eigenvectors of $A$?
2. If I set the constraint that all diagonal elements of $P$ are $1$, then is $P$ unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, that is correct.
2. No. Suppose that $A=D=\operatorname{Id}$. Then if $P$ is *any* invertible matrix, you will have $P^{-1}AP=D$.

Comment: Thank @Jose for your answer! For the second question, yes, any invertible $P$ can do but if I request all diagonal entries of $P$ must be 1, is this $P$ unique? In your example, I think $P=Id$ is only the solution where the diagonal is 1.

Comment: There are infinitely many invertible matrices with only $1$'s in their main diagonal. If, for instance, $n=2$, any matrix of the form $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&x\\y&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ will work as long as $xy\neq-1$.

Comment: How about the general case, i.e. $A$ in general not very special like $Id$?

Comment: Even if $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues there is more than one possible $P$ having only $1$'s in the main diagonal.

Comment: I agree with you, Jose! I now would like to find a condition so that $P$ is unique. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: That's another question and I suggest that you post it as such. Did I answer your question or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101595/discussion-between-trung-dung-tran-and-jose-carlos-santos).